# How to remove duplicate occurrences in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am new to bash programming (grep/uniq/sort/etc...) and I am having trouble trying to remove duplicates from a file with the given format

```
--
name: joe
tag: 123
--
name: mike
tag: 000
--
name: dave
tag: 123
--
name: loopy
tag: 123
--
```

Basically what I want is to remove the duplicates in the file which have the same tag number, like this:

```
--
name: joe
tag: 123
--
name: mike
tag: 000
--
```

Comment: If name and tag were same line, that'd be easy...

Comment: I agree... but they're not...

Comment: You can easily get them on the same line by using either `paste` or `xargs` this will do the trick `grep -v - file | xargs -n4 | sort -uk4` however the output isn't in the desired format. @Thor answers is best here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task is a pretty good fit for awk. If you have gawk or mawk available, you can accomplish it by setting the record separator appropriately:

```
awk -v RS='--\n' -v ORS='--\n' '!h[$4]++' infile
```

Output:

```
--
name: joe
tag: 123
--
name: mike
tag: 000
--
```

This works by remembering which tags have been seen (`h[$4]++`), i.e. fourth element in each record. The bang (`!`) in front of the increment ensures that the condition is only true when `h[$4]` is zero, so the default rule (`{ print $0 }`) is only invoked the first time tag is seen.

A slightly shorter version:

```
awk '!h[$4]++' RS='--\n' ORS='--\n' infile
```

#### Edit - handle records where name fields have spaces

The field count would vary if the name field has spaces. You can handle this by doing the field splitting a bit differently:

```
awk '!h[$4]++' RS='--\n' ORS='--\n' FS='\n| *: *' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/name/{x=$0}/tag/{a[$0]++;if(a[$0]<2){print "--\n"x,"\n",$0"\n--"}}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
--
name: joe
tag: 123
--
name: mike
tag: 000
--
name: dave
tag: 123
--
name: loopy
tag: 123
--
> awk '/name/{x=$0}/tag/{a[$0]++;if(a[$0]<2){print "--\n"x,"\n",$0"\n--"}}' temp
--
name: joe 
 tag: 123
--
--
name: mike 
 tag: 000
--
```

`/name/`{store line in a variable here so that if the next tag is not a duplicate we can use this temporary variable.}

`/tag/`{build an associative array with the count of the line.more than one leads to a duplicate.so print only if the count is 1}

Comment: Hey thanks! Can you elaborate a little more on what's going on. Looks crazy!

Comment: Sweet stuff. Can you recommend any good tutorials on where I can start with bash programming?

Comment: why dont you google it :https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=hp&tok=Na74BgjYu69vLwt7Txo0NQ&cp=12&gs_id=1a&xhr=t&q=bash+scripting&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=bash+scripti&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.Yms&fp=c13a537f28efa0a7&biw=1259&bih=770

Answer (score -2):

If foobar is the file that contains the lines to remove duplicates:

```
awk '{ if (arry[$3]++ == 0) print $0; }' foobar
```

the $3 in the array says to remove duplicates based on the values in the 3rd column only.  If you want to remove entire duplicated lines, use $0 instead.

Using awk this way has the added advantage of not changing the order of the input lines (which sort/uniq does).